# How to remove all Magento Connect Extensions

Tags: magento-1.7, extensions, magento-connect

I am trying to remove extensions that were previously installed, but the only way I have been able to do it is editing the module files under app/etc/modules and changing

```
<active>true</active>
```

to

```
<active>false</active>
```

Is there a way to completely remove the extension as if I had never installed in the first place?

When I view my Magento Connect Manager, none of my extensions appear under the existing extensions list.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You are able to remove all the models via the Mage Connect interface:

```
System > Magento Connect > Magento Connect Manager
```

Set all the modules to uninstall and then they are getting removed.

Comment: But pay attention that executed setup scripts are not reverted. So there may still be tables, columns or attributes in the database, which have to be reverted manually.

Comment: There is still no way in magento to do this, correct :-(

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt how about https://github.com/magento-hackathon/MageTrashApp ?

Comment: Apparently none of my extensions have appeared in the Magento Connect Manager (as written in the question). Does anyone know why this might occur?

Comment: I don't have any clue how magento connect works to be honest, but I think they only appear, if you install them via connect. So I would assume, they are not installed via connect. They are installed manually.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there's no foolproof way to fully remove extension once it's installed to the system.

While it's easy to remove bootstrap file from app/etc/modules and main code from app/code/{codePool}, there's no way to determine what other payload this extension had. By investigating code, configuration and resource files, it's possible to locate majority of additional tables, translation files, templates, layouts, database objects, stylesheet, JS-s and images, but even after major detective work there's good chance the some leftovers remain.

Also, it's almost impossible to remove payment methods, as Magento store references to them to orders and invoices and so on. Once you remove them, any attempt to view those orders will cause PHP level (uncaught) error.

Comment: It's often a beautifully complex and manual process which if the module installed custom attributes with their own model definitions, will make the module unremovable until the attributes it added are dereferenced and manually ripped out of EAV. Good times to be had by all... Many's the Magento newb who went all module happy till the site went south, only to find the damage is unrecoverable at their level of db admin experience because they cannot remove the offending module or the other modules they find to be useless. STBY if you find this out after a year or so of operation.